Googletrans AttibutError
While importing Translator from googletrans -4.0.0rc1 I get the following error:
AttributeError: module 'httpcore' has no attribute 'UnsupportedProtocol'

Can someone help?
I also tried installing version 3.0 but still got an error.

httpx==0.13.3
httpcore==0.9
U problem is not in Google translator itself, but in the dependencies.
Put these versions in the libraries.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
